# Web View not acting as UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview, uiwebview

I've scoured the internet for 3 hours now, and have just given up. I figured since no one else on this entire planet has had this problem before, maybe I should ask the stackoverflow community, and see what happens.

I'm familiar with xCode, and objective C, but am learning swift. For my first app I figured I'd build a super simple webview app that loads a page. Easy right? I can code this in about 15 seconds in objective c, and I did, it works fine. Maybe there's something I'm missing here.

When I attempt to connect the object to the UIWebView it won't connect.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet var textBox: UITextField!

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

[Image of it not connecting. It's not connecting like it should](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsfbv.png)

Comment: I think you pulled this code from somewhere in SO as i rmb, what i do to fix is bring those code from `loadView ` to  `viewDidLoad ` and use `addSubview` instead of `view = webView`, the one u connect from storyboard is `UIWebView`, not `WKWebView`, `WKWebView` is programatically only

Answer (score 1):

Change type from **WKWebView** to **UIWebView**.You have added UIWebView from object library which your are trying to connect to a WKWebView object so it will not connect. WKWebview has to be added programmatically as it is not present in object library.

These two classes have similar functionalities but they are not connected to each other in anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code to build a webView app that loads a page.

```
import UIKit

class ADKWebViewDemoViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var webview: UIWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webview.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")!))
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```